# As3Iso: Why use a secondary display list?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, isometric

I am porting as3iso to use with my abstract display list but I fail to see the reason why the author decided to use a secondary display list (the node hierarchy). I cannot think of the necessity of this apart from being able to get the children array of a display object. Is it really that big a performance hit to do for(i in 0...numChildren) getChildAt vs getting the children array? This can also be mitigated by maintaining a children array while overriding.

The only other reason is that some properties of flash.display.DisplayObject are final and wanting to have x and y correlate to isoX/isoY, but worldX/worldY is a reasonable API for this.

I have no problem with the secondary display list but I fail to see the point and am leaning toward having my iso display objects extend from my DisplayObject.

Also, I had presumed that marking objects visible=false that are not on the screen or outside of a scrollRect is not necessary with Flash and in rendering in general as this is/should be handled at the renderer level? Is this the case with the flash software renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way the library doesn't rely on the rendering system. You can use the traditional flash display list, Stage3D or a custom solution.

Answer (score 4):

For the last question, it's useful to set `visible=false` because that way the renderer can quickly skip this object without having to calculate whether it is within the screen rectangle or not.